# How to keep Dairy farm & manure odour out of my house?

Tags: smell

I have recently inherited 7000 sq ft of land where I want to construct a house with a back-lawn.
The issue is that the land in discussion is adjacent to a small dairy farm, I counted roughly 20 Buffalos.

When I visited the land, i could smell the manure. The distance between the Cow shed and my wall would be about 50 ft to 60 ft. So my question is how can i keep the smell out of my lawn so it doesn't affect my time spent out in the lawn, and keep the odour from getting in the house.

The odour wasn't very strong, but it was there. The real estate agent suggested bushy trees to create a separation and change of airflow. but how much of a difference would that make?

Secondly, it's Winters here, it was about 16 C when I visited the land. Would the odour be more pronounced in summer ? during rain ? etc ?

Other option is to straight out sell it and not think of constructing there at all.

Help me out please.

Comment: Welcome to rural living... Part of the answer is that you get used to it and stop noticing it, much like you stop noticing traffic noise. Or, as you said, you can consider turning it into cash and building elsewhere.

Comment: Future use of the adjacent land can make a huge difference to your decision making. Is it possible that cows will be replaced by pigs? Or alfalfa?

Comment: If you attempt to seal your house to such an extent that you don't detect outsided gases your indoor air quality will be worse than outside. Your question is off topic here. It's too broad and you haven't provided any information about your home plans.

Answer (score 2):

So much important information missing:

Prevailing wind direction: will it blow towards you or away?

Are you in a valley so the wind is funneled in your direction?

I live where there are cows / horses and grew up in the countryside - I notice those smells but have lived with them all my life. If they are cleaning out the cowshed i know i will smell more - know that work, understand that work, even done that work.

Boils down to if you understand the countryside and it smells over seasons etc then enjoy the land however you wish, if not then move to a place, like the city, you are comfortable in.

Comment: Wind could blow anywhere. 
And no it's not a funnel. it's a wide open land to the left and right. The farm is not right behind my land. it's on the side of the land right behind mine. The land right behind mine is the living area of the farm owner. so imagine 2x2 bricks. The bricks to the right are my land and the owner house. The bricks to the left are the farm and the  open land.

Comment: @MuhammadAli do you know what "prevailing wind direction" means?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to keep the odours out of your home or out of your backyard.  That comes with the setting.

You're going to smell it, but you may get used to it.

If it gets warm there in the summer, the odours will likely intensify.  It does depend, however, if there is a natural summertime breeze in the direction that will blow the odours in the other direction.

There are 20 head now, but what's the limit?  What you are smelling now may not be from the maximum capacity for animals on the neighboring property.  Remember, the dairy farmer next door can change plans or likely can sell at any time too (perhaps to someone with more/different animals, or animals in different locations on their property).

My recommendation?  Enjoy the smells, or sell.  Perhaps the dairy farmer would like to purchase the land you inherited from you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it's likely to get worse.  So, either get used to it or move.  Options to mitigate it

- Get an AC unit that has air filtering
- Don't open windows on the farm side
- Make your outdoor area on the other side, so that your house is in between it and the farm.

No matter what you plant, the smell **will** come over some of the time

- based on talking to people living near a settling pond.  A settling pond is where the sewage from a township is left to cure naturally (in an enclosed body of water).

If you are planting, the air/wind is blocked 2 to 1.  So, if the tree is 2m high, it should provide a buffer zone of 4m.

- based on council interactions to do with noise/sound from the local airport.